# Crash of app with low memory when converting video into frames in ios 5.1(with ARC)

Tags: ios5, automatic-ref-counting, avfoundation, video-capture

I had captured the video using AVFoundation and When I am trying to convert the video captured into Frames my app is crashed coz of low memory. I am using the project with ios 5.1 and ARC enabled.

Here my code follows:

```
-(void) makeVideoCall
{
    videoOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc]init];
    [captureSession addOutput:videoOutput];
    videoOutput.videoSettings =
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]
                                forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];
    videoOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = YES;
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("MyQueue", NULL);
    [videoOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];
    dispatch_release(queue);

    [videoOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];
    [captureSession startRunning];
}

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"\n Inside CaptureOutput....");

    CGImageRef tempImage = [self imageRefFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
    image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:tempImage scale:0.2 orientation:UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored];
}

-(CGImageRef)imageRefFromSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer {

    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer); 
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0); 
    uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer); 
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer); 
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer); 
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer); 

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(); 
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst); 
    CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context); 
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
    CGContextRelease(context); 
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    return newImage;

}
```

Anyone pls advice me what to do.

Regards,
Monish.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use  CFRelease(cgImageRef) to release the CGImageRef object. 
You can go to Xcode and in the Product bar click Analyze. It will help you to analyze your code and probably give you possible memory leaks.